Algorithm to Finding Faces on a Planar Graph (C++)
I'm working on an algorithms' assignment at my college, which involves finding the vertices that belong to the face of a strictly planar and connected graph. However, I've encountered an issue with one of the test cases, and I'm not sure how to resolve it. I'm finding one extra face than I should with my current method of visiting the vertices/edges. Could someone give me a hint?
I'm correctly identifying the faces in two test cases I have access to. However, depending on where the starting point is and where it's connected, for instance, I find one extra face, which is incorrect. How can I fix this?
My logic for visiting and finding all the faces was to transform each edge into two directed ones, keeping track of which ones I've visited or not. To choose the next one to visit, I calculate the angle (arctan) between two points and visit the next one in counterclockwise order.
I'm sorting for each vertex its edges that connect it to its neighbors, cyclically, using arctan. In this way, I can order the edges counterclockwise.
Utility Functions:
relativeInclination: Calculates the relative inclination between two points.
sort_connections: Sorts the connections of a point i based on its relative inclination with respect to the reference point.
printFaces: Prints the faces of the graph.
DFS Function:
The dfs function is a modified depth-first search (DFS) to find the faces of the graph.
It takes as parameters the index of the current point (i), the index of the current connection (j), the total number of vertices (n), the graph (graph), a visited matrix (visited), and the positions of the vertices (positions).
The DFS traverses the graph starting from each unvisited vertex and marks the visited vertices and connections.
Upon finding a cycle or an edge, it ends the current face and adds it to the faces vector.
Main Function:
Reads the number of vertices (n) and the number of edges (m).
Initializes the data structures to represent the graph, visits, and vertex positions.
For each vertex, it reads its coordinates and connections with other vertices, updating the graph and the visited matrix.
Sorts the connections of each vertex based on its relative inclination with respect to that vertex.
Starts the depth-first search (DFS) from each unvisited vertex.
Prints the found faces.
Output:
The output consists of printing the number of faces and then, for each face, printing the number of vertices it consists of and the indices of those vertices.
Example:
some graph
In this image, I have any planar and connected graph.
enter image description here
In this other image, I have the same graph, but in the way my code sees it, with one edge going and another one returning, instead of the original edge. That is, I direct the edge and duplicate it.
enter image description here
In this other image, I have any vertex connected to four other vertices. The first edge, using my code's ordering, would be (X, D), the second (X, A), the third (X, B), and the fourth (X, C). But, just like a clock, this operates cyclically, so even though (X, D) is the first concerning my vertex X, the one that comes before it (cyclically) is (X, C). It's important to keep this in mind when choosing edges counterclockwise.
Input Format: Each test case consists of several lines. The first line contains two integers, N and M, representing respectively the number of vertices and edges of the input graph G. It is guaranteed that G is connected, 1 ≤ N, M ≤ 10^5, and V(G) = {1, 2, . . . , N}. The i-th line of the input starts with two real numbers xi, yi, representing the coordinates of vertex i in the Cartesian plane; it is guaranteed that −10^4 ≤ xi, yi ≤ 10^4. In the same line, we have a positive integer di, representing the degree of vertex i. Still on the same line, we have di integers between 1 and N, each corresponding to a neighbor of i; it is guaranteed that a vertex is not a neighbor of itself.
Output Format: The first line of the output contains an integer F, which should be equal to the number of faces of G. The next F lines should correspond to the F faces of G; each line starts with an integer Si, representing the size of the i-th face of G; then there are Si integers, representing the circuit corresponding to the edge of the face. The order of the faces is not important, but consecutive vertices on the edge of the face should be adjacent.
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

#define _ ios_base::sync_with_stdio(0);cin.tie(0);
#define ff first
#define ss second
#define pb push_back

vector<int> face;
vector<vector<int>> faces;

double relativeInclination(double x1, double x2, double y1, double y2){
    return atan2(y1 - y2, x1 - x2);
}

vector<int> sort_connections(int i, vector<int>& connections, vector<pair<double, double>> pos){
    double x_ref = pos[i].first;
    double y_ref = pos[i].second;
    sort(connections.begin(), connections.end(), [&](double a, double b) {
        double incl_a = relativeInclination(pos[a].first, x_ref, pos[a].second, y_ref);
        double incl_b = relativeInclination(pos[b].first, x_ref, pos[b].second, y_ref);
        return incl_a < incl_b;
    });

    return connections;
}


void printFaces(){
    cout << faces.size() << endl;
    for(int i = 0; i < faces.size(); i++){
        cout << faces[i].size() << " ";
        for(int j = 0;  j < faces[i].size(); j++){
            cout << faces[i][j]+1 << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}

void dfs(int b, int i, int j, int n, vector<vector<int>>& graph, vector<vector<bool>>& visited, vector<pair<double, double>>& positions){

    visited[i][j] = true;

    if (b == n) {
        face.pb(b);
        faces.push_back(face);
        face.clear();
        return;
    }

    int k = 0;
    while(true){
        if(graph[n][k] == i){
            k++; 
            break;
        }
        k++;
    }

    for(; k <= graph[n].size(); k++){
        if(k == graph[n].size()) k = 0;
        if(!visited[n][k]) break;
    }
            
    face.pb(n);
    dfs(b, n, k, graph[n][k], graph, visited, positions);
}

int main (){

    int n, m; cin >> n >> m;

    vector<vector<int>> graph(n);
    vector<vector<bool>> visited(n);
    vector<pair<double, double>> positions(n); 

    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        double x, y; cin >> x >> y;

        pair<double, double> v; v.ff = x, v.ss = y;
        positions[i] = v;

        int k; cin >> k;
        while (k--){
            int a; cin >> a; a--;
            graph[i].pb(a); visited[i].pb(false);
        }
        
    }

    
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        graph[i] = sort_connections(i, graph[i], positions);
    }


    for(int i = 0; i < visited.size(); i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < visited[i].size(); j++){
            if(!visited[i][j]) {
                face.pb(i);
                dfs(i, i, j, graph[i][j], graph, visited, positions);
            }
        }
    }

    printFaces();

    return 0;
}

I'm putting the tests in code format because the formatting isn't correct in text format
First Test

8 11 
0 0 2 2 3
1 1 4 1 4 5 7
1 -1 5 1 4 5 6 7
2 0 2 2 3
4 0 3 2 3 6
4 -1.5 2 3 5
-3 0 3 2 3 8
-2 0 1 7

Expected Output

5
6 2 5 6 3 7 2
7 3 7 8 7 2 1 3
5 1 2 4 3 1
5 5 3 4 2 5
4 6 3 5 6

My output

5
7 1 3 7 8 7 2 1 
5 1 2 4 3 1 
6 2 7 3 6 5 2 
5 2 5 3 4 2 
4 3 5 6 3 

In the first test, my output is correct, the order doesn't matter, just the vertex that are part of the face.

Second Test

12 23
-3 1 2 2 8 
-1 2 5 1 3 5 7 8
0.5 3 3 2 5 4 
2.5 1.65 3 3 5 6 
0.5 1.65 5 2 3 4 6 7
2 0.15 4 4 5 7 10
0 0.5 6 2 5 6 8 9 10
-1.5 0.5 4 1 2 7 9
-0.75 -1.5 4 7 8 10 11 
1.75 -1.4 5 6 7 9 11 12 
0.25 -3 3 9 10 12
2.9 -2.85 2 10 11

Expected Output

13
11 1 8 9 11 12 10 6 4 3 2 1
4 1 2 8 1
4 3 2 5 3
4 2 8 7 2
4 2 5 7 2
4 3 4 5 3
4 5 7 6 5
4 5 4 6 5
4 7 8 9 7
4 7 9 10 7
4 7 6 10 7
4 9 10 11 9
4 10 11 12 10

My output

13
11 1 8 9 11 12 10 6 4 3 2 1 
4 1 2 8 1 
4 2 7 8 2 
4 2 5 7 2 
4 2 3 5 2 
4 3 4 5 3 
4 4 6 5 4 
4 5 6 7 5 
4 6 10 7 6 
4 7 9 8 7 
4 7 10 9 7 
4 9 10 11 9 
4 10 12 11 10 

In the second one as well.

Third Test

11 15
0 0 3 2 3 9 
1 1 4 1 4 5 7 
1 -1 5 1 4 5 6 7 
2 0 2 2 3
4 0 3 2 3 6 
4 -1.5 2 3 5
-3 0 3 2 3 8
-2 0 1 7
0.5 0 3 1 10 11
0.75 0.5 2 11 9
0.75 -0.5 2 10 9

Expected output

6
10 1 3 4 2 1 9 10 11 9 1
7 1 2 7 8 7 3 1
6 2 5 6 3 7 2
5 2 4 3 5 2
4 3 6 5 3
4 9 11 10 9

My output

7 
7 1 3 7 8 7 2 1 
6 1 9 11 10 9 1 
5 1 2 4 3 1 
6 2 7 3 6 5 2 
5 2 5 3 4 2 
4 3 5 6 3 
4 9 10 11 9 

In the third one, it's wrong. It identifies one extra face.
What should I do?

Do not post questions tagged with both the [tag:c] and [tag:c++] tags unless you particularly like the idea of being downvoted.  You're working in C++; C++ is the appropriate tag.

People generally look askance at code using <bits/stdc++.h>, not least because it is not defined by the C++ standard and therefore may not exist on some platforms or may contain different material on different platforms.

And if you are using <bits/stdc++.h> for speed, note that including the entire C++ Standard Library, a huge number of files to be opened and compiled, is pretty damn slow, typically slowing the build time of the including file by an order of magnitude unless you have your build tools configured exactly right for precompliled headers. If the code works the first or second time, maybe you come out ahead. After that you start losing time on every build.

#define endl '\n' -- Do not do this.  Also, your code is hard to follow all because of those nutty #define macros.

Post your test cases as text, not images.  Why did you post your code as text, but the test data as an image?  I am not referring to the images of the graph, the actual numeric test data should be posted as text.

It is hard to tell how your algorithm work with this ugly competition coding style, but it looks like you are trying to traverse the graph taking a left turn at every junction. Not every loop you find this way corresponds to a face. Some will be anti-faces (clockwise loops instead of counterclockwise) and others will be degenerate faces (not enclosing any area).

Agree with @n. m. could be an AI, your cycle 1,9,11,10,9,1 encloses no area on the part 1,9 and the actual part 9,11,10,9 is included later (as DimK points out also). Your algorithm needs adjusting to exclude that. Maybe can’t start/end using the same connector in reverse directions.

@n.m.couldbeanAI If you split the undirected edges into pairs of directed half-edges then you can always generate the face bounded by those edges by following each successive half-edge clockwise from the previous edge until you get back to the starting edge. Repeat from the next unvisited edge until all edges are visited and you will have generated all the faces (just from following clockwise edges).

@MT0 there is a counterexample to this claim in the other answer. You cannot determine locally what is clockwise and what is counterclockwise.

@n.m.couldbeanAI DimK's answer does not support that conclusion - they are just pointing out where the OP's algorithm was wrong (as it stops iterating edges when it returns to the start vertex and not when it returns to the starting half-edge). You can always find the faces by following half-edges until you get back the the start (and every undirected edge in the graph can be replaced with an equivalent pair of half-edges each in opposite directions and each of those two half-edges in opposite directions will be part of a different face).

@MT0 You are right I didn't read it carefully the first time.

Interesting algorithmic problem. I cannot provide a solution at the moment, however by drawing the graph given in the third test case, the mistake becomes apparent:

In the image above the vertices and faces are numbered in accordance with the input and expected output data.
Your program identifies faces 2-6, however it counts 6 twice, the second time adding vertex 1 to it. It also fails to correctly identify face 1, treating it as the entire square formed by vertices 1,3,4,2.

You're right, that's where I go wrong. I found the solution to this type of test, and I believe it applies to any other as well. The mistake in this test is that I start from a vertex that has a bridge edge (an edge that, if removed from the graph, will create 1 additional connected component), so it identifies a face incorrectly. In this sense, I find all the vertices that have bridge edges and leave them to be visited last, prioritizing the vertices that don't have bridge edges

I'm waiting for more test cases, but I guess it's everything right.

If you split the undirected edges into pairs of directed half-edges (each in opposite directions) then you can always generate the face bounded by a half-edge by following each successive half-edge clockwise from the previous half-edge until you get back to the starting half-edge. Repeat from the next unvisited half-edge until all half-edges are visited and you will have generated all the faces (just from following clockwise edges).

In your example, if you have the (clockwise) cyclic edge ordering:



Vertex
Adjacent Vertices




1
2, 9, 3


2
5, 4, 1, 7


3
7, 1, 4, 5, 6


4
2, 3


5
2, 6, 3


6
5, 3


7
2, 8, 3


8
7


9
10, 11, 1


10
11, 9


11
10, 9



Then you can follow from one edge to each successive clockwise edge until you get back to the starting edge (not vertex).
I.e.
(1 -> 3), (3 -> 4), (4 -> 2), (2 -> 1) don't stop there (even though you've reached the starting vertex) (1 -> 9), (9 -> 10), (10 -> 11), (11 -> 9), (9 -> 1), (1 -> 3) which gets you back to the starting edge and gives you the bounds of the f1 face.
Which, if you continue following clockwise edges until you get back to the start, gives the faces:



Face
Edges




f1
1 -> 3 -> 4 -> 2 -> 1 -> 9 -> 10 -> 11 -> 9 -> 1


f2
1 -> 2 -> 7 -> 8 -> 7 -> 3 -> 1


f3
2 -> 5 -> 6 -> 3 -> 7 -> 2


f4
3 -> 5 -> 2 -> 4 -> 3


f5
3 -> 6 -> 5 -> 3


f6
9 -> 11 -> 10 -> 9




In Python, the code would be:
from __future__ import annotations

from math import atan2


class Vertex:
    graph: Graph
    _index: int
    x: float
    y: float
    edges: list[Edge]

    def __init__(self: Vertex, graph: Graph, index: int, x: float, y: float) -> None:
        self.graph = graph
        self._index = index
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.edges = []
        graph.add_vertex(self)

    @property
    def index(self) -> int:
        return self._index + 1

    def add_edge(self: Vertex, edge: Edge) -> None:
        self.edges.append(edge)

    def sort_edges(self: Vertex) -> None:
        vertex = self

        class EdgeAngleComparator:
            edge: Edge
            def __init__(self: EdgeAngleComparator, edge: Edge) -> None:
                self.edge = edge

            def __lt__(self: EdgeAngleComparator, other: EdgeAngleComparator) -> bool:
                return self.edge.angle(vertex) > other.edge.angle(vertex)

        self.edges.sort(key=EdgeAngleComparator)

        for edge, nxt in zip(self.edges, self.edges[1:] + self.edges[:1]):
            edge.set_next(self, nxt)

    def __str__(self: Vertex) -> str:
        return "{index:2d}: Coordinates ({x: 2.2f}, {y: 2.2f}) - Edges [{edges}]".format(
            index=self.index,
            x=self.x,
            y=self.y,
            edges=", ".join(str(edge) for edge in self.edges),
        )


class Edge:
    src: Vertex
    dest: Vertex
    visited_forwards: bool
    visited_backwards: bool
    src_next: Optional[Edge]
    dest_next: Optional[Edge]

    def __init__(self: Edge, graph: Graph, src: Vertex, dest: Vertex) -> None:
        self.graph = Graph
        self.src = src
        self.dest = dest
        self.src_next = None
        self.dest_next = None
        self.reset_visits()
        graph.add_edge(self)
        src.add_edge(self)
        dest.add_edge(self)

    def other_end(self: Edge, end: Vertex) -> Vertex:
        if end is self.src:
            return self.dest
        if end is self.dest:
            return self.src
        raise ValueError

    def angle(self: Edge, end: Vertex) -> float:
        other = self.other_end(end)
        return atan2(end.y - other.y, end.x - other.x)

    def set_next(self: Edge, vertex: Vertex, next: Edge) -> None:
        if vertex is self.src:
            self.src_next = next
        elif vertex is self.dest:
            self.dest_next = next
        else:
            raise ValueError

    def reset_visits(self: Edge) -> None:
        self.visited_backwards = False
        self.visited_forwards = False

    def visit(self: Edge, vertex: Vertex) -> tuple[Edge, Vertex]:
        if vertex is self.src:
            if self.visited_forwards:
                raise ValueError
            self.visited_forwards = True
            return (self.dest_next, self.dest)
        if vertex is self.dest:
            if self.visited_backwards:
                raise ValueError
            self.visited_backwards = True
            return (self.src_next, self.src)
        raise ValueError

    def __str__(self: Edge) -> str:
        return f"({self.src.index:2d}, {self.dest.index:2d})"

class Graph:
    @staticmethod
    def read(input: str) -> Graph:
        lines = input.split("\n")
        num_vertices, num_edges = lines[0].strip().split(" ")
        graph = Graph()
        for idx, vertex_line in enumerate(lines[1:]):
            x, y, _num_adjacent, *adjacent = vertex_line.strip().split(" ")
            vertex = Vertex(graph, idx, float(x), float(y))
            for adj in adjacent:
                adj_index = int(adj) - 1
                if adj_index < idx:
                    edge = Edge(graph, vertex, graph.vertices[adj_index])

        graph.sort_edges()
        return graph

    def __init__(self: Graph) -> None:
        self.vertices = []
        self.edges = []

    def add_vertex(self: Graph, vertex: Vertex) -> None:
        self.vertices.append(vertex)

    def add_edge(self: Graph, edge: Edge) -> None:
        self.edges.append(edge)

    def sort_edges(self: Graph) -> None:
        for vertex in self.vertices:
            vertex.sort_edges()

    def faces(self: Graph) -> list[Face]:
        faces: list[Face] = []

        for edge in self.edges:
            edge.reset_visits()

        for edge in self.edges:
            if not edge.visited_forwards:
                faces.append(Face(edge, edge.src))
            if not edge.visited_backwards:
                faces.append(Face(edge, edge.dest))

        return faces

    def __str__(self: Graph) -> str:
        return (
            "Vertices\n"
            + "\n".join(str(vertex) for vertex in self.vertices)
            + "\nFaces\n"
            + "\n".join(str(face) for face in self.faces())
        )


class Face:
    start_vertex: Vertex
    edges: list[Edge]

    def __init__(self: Face, start_edge: Edge, start_vertex: Vertex) -> None:
        self.start_vertex = start_vertex
        self.edges = []
        edge = start_edge
        vertex = start_vertex
        while True:
            self.edges.append(edge)
            edge, vertex = edge.visit(vertex)
            if edge is start_edge:
                break

    @property
    def vertices(self) -> generator[Vertex, None, None]:
        vertex = self.start_vertex
        for edge in self.edges:
            yield vertex
            vertex = edge.other_end(vertex)

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return "[{vertices}]".format(
            vertices = ", ".join(f"{vertex.index:2d}" for vertex in self.vertices),
        )

print("Graph 1")
print(
    Graph.read(
        """8 11
0 0 2 2 3
1 1 4 1 4 5 7
1 -1 5 1 4 5 6 7
2 0 2 2 3
4 0 3 2 3 6
4 -1.5 2 3 5
-3 0 3 2 3 8
-2 0 1 7""",
    ),
)

print("Graph 2")
print(
    Graph.read(
        """12 23
-3 1 2 2 8 
-1 2 5 1 3 5 7 8
0.5 3 3 2 5 4 
2.5 1.65 3 3 5 6 
0.5 1.65 5 2 3 4 6 7
2 0.15 4 4 5 7 10
0 0.5 6 2 5 6 8 9 10
-1.5 0.5 4 1 2 7 9
-0.75 -1.5 4 7 8 10 11 
1.75 -1.4 5 6 7 9 11 12 
0.25 -3 3 9 10 12
2.9 -2.85 2 10 11""",
    ),
)

print("Graph 3")
print(
    Graph.read(
        """11 15
0 0 3 2 3 9
1 1 4 1 4 5 7
1 -1 5 1 4 5 6 7
2 0 2 2 3
4 0 3 2 3 6
4 -1.5 2 3 5
-3 0 3 2 3 8
-2 0 1 7
0.5 0 3 1 10 11
0.75 0.5 2 11 9
0.75 -0.5 2 10 9""",
    ),
)

Which outputs:
Graph 1
Vertices
 1: Coordinates ( 0.00,  0.00) - Edges [( 3,  1), ( 2,  1)]
 2: Coordinates ( 1.00,  1.00) - Edges [( 5,  2), ( 4,  2), ( 2,  1), ( 7,  2)]
 3: Coordinates ( 1.00, -1.00) - Edges [( 6,  3), ( 7,  3), ( 3,  1), ( 4,  3), ( 5,  3)]
 4: Coordinates ( 2.00,  0.00) - Edges [( 4,  3), ( 4,  2)]
 5: Coordinates ( 4.00,  0.00) - Edges [( 6,  5), ( 5,  3), ( 5,  2)]
 6: Coordinates ( 4.00, -1.50) - Edges [( 6,  3), ( 6,  5)]
 7: Coordinates (-3.00,  0.00) - Edges [( 8,  7), ( 7,  3), ( 7,  2)]
 8: Coordinates (-2.00,  0.00) - Edges [( 8,  7)]
Faces
[ 2,  1,  3,  4]
[ 1,  2,  7,  8,  7,  3]
[ 2,  4,  3,  5]
[ 2,  5,  6,  3,  7]
[ 5,  3,  6]
Graph 2
Vertices
 1: Coordinates (-3.00,  1.00) - Edges [( 8,  1), ( 2,  1)]
 2: Coordinates (-1.00,  2.00) - Edges [( 5,  2), ( 7,  2), ( 8,  2), ( 2,  1), ( 3,  2)]
 3: Coordinates ( 0.50,  3.00) - Edges [( 4,  3), ( 5,  3), ( 3,  2)]
 4: Coordinates ( 2.50,  1.65) - Edges [( 6,  4), ( 5,  4), ( 4,  3)]
 5: Coordinates ( 0.50,  1.65) - Edges [( 5,  4), ( 6,  5), ( 7,  5), ( 5,  2), ( 5,  3)]
 6: Coordinates ( 2.00,  0.15) - Edges [(10,  6), ( 7,  6), ( 6,  5), ( 6,  4)]
 7: Coordinates ( 0.00,  0.50) - Edges [( 7,  6), (10,  7), ( 9,  7), ( 8,  7), ( 7,  2), ( 7,  5)]
 8: Coordinates (-1.50,  0.50) - Edges [( 8,  7), ( 9,  8), ( 8,  1), ( 8,  2)]
 9: Coordinates (-0.75, -1.50) - Edges [(11,  9), ( 9,  8), ( 9,  7), (10,  9)]
10: Coordinates ( 1.75, -1.40) - Edges [(12, 10), (11, 10), (10,  9), (10,  7), (10,  6)]
11: Coordinates ( 0.25, -3.00) - Edges [(11,  9), (11, 10), (12, 11)]
12: Coordinates ( 2.90, -2.85) - Edges [(12, 11), (12, 10)]
Faces
[ 2,  1,  8]
[ 1,  2,  3,  4,  6, 10, 12, 11,  9,  8]
[ 3,  2,  5]
[ 4,  3,  5]
[ 5,  2,  7]
[ 4,  5,  6]
[ 6,  5,  7]
[ 7,  2,  8]
[ 6,  7, 10]
[ 7,  8,  9]
[ 7,  9, 10]
[10,  9, 11]
[10, 11, 12]
Graph 3
Vertices
 1: Coordinates ( 0.00,  0.00) - Edges [( 9,  1), ( 3,  1), ( 2,  1)]
 2: Coordinates ( 1.00,  1.00) - Edges [( 5,  2), ( 4,  2), ( 2,  1), ( 7,  2)]
 3: Coordinates ( 1.00, -1.00) - Edges [( 6,  3), ( 7,  3), ( 3,  1), ( 4,  3), ( 5,  3)]
 4: Coordinates ( 2.00,  0.00) - Edges [( 4,  3), ( 4,  2)]
 5: Coordinates ( 4.00,  0.00) - Edges [( 6,  5), ( 5,  3), ( 5,  2)]
 6: Coordinates ( 4.00, -1.50) - Edges [( 6,  3), ( 6,  5)]
 7: Coordinates (-3.00,  0.00) - Edges [( 8,  7), ( 7,  3), ( 7,  2)]
 8: Coordinates (-2.00,  0.00) - Edges [( 8,  7)]
 9: Coordinates ( 0.50,  0.00) - Edges [(11,  9), ( 9,  1), (10,  9)]
10: Coordinates ( 0.75,  0.50) - Edges [(11, 10), (10,  9)]
11: Coordinates ( 0.75, -0.50) - Edges [(11,  9), (11, 10)]
Faces
[ 2,  1,  9, 10, 11,  9,  1,  3,  4]
[ 1,  2,  7,  8,  7,  3]
[ 2,  4,  3,  5]
[ 2,  5,  6,  3,  7]
[ 5,  3,  6]
[10,  9, 11]


I tested for the second input and got the wrong answer. But the logic that you describe looks good.

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/main.py", line 192, in 
g1 = Graph.read(
File "/home/main.py", line 121, in read
adj_index = int(adj) - 1
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
That was the error.

@NicolasVonDolinger That is an issue with the data as it has trailing spaces on some lines. Remove those trailing spaces (either in the input data or by stripping them when you read the lines) and the code works. I've updated it to strip the spaces and included the output for all the graphs.
